# How can javascript like varName.myFunction()

Tags: javascript

```
function CircleArea(Value) {
   var Results = 3.14 * Value^2;
   return Results;
}
```

So I want:

```
var Diameter = 30;
Diameter.CircleArea(); // Results 2826
```

Like:

```
var n = 30; n.toString() // Results 30
```

Syntax:

```
varName.myFunction();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a function to a number?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
Also look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [but rarely should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) extend prototypes:

```
Number.prototype.circleArea = function() {
  var value = this;
  return Math.pow(value, 2) * Math.PI;
};

var num = 30;
console.log(num.circleArea()); // 2827.4333882308138
```

Comment: @pro2014learning I think I should have emphasized `but rarely should` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts an argument .

So you will need to pass in Diameter like so :

```
CirclArea(Diameter)
```

Returns  2826